# some feature of application is not loading in production server sometime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, networking, sql-server-2012

We have an asp.net application where sqlserver 2012 is being used as back end.There is a tab called 'Screening' which can be used to search for data for different categories,let's say 'A'and'B'.'A' has 124 records and 'B' has 924 records.The screening section is always working fine for 'A' in production server.
however it may take more than 10 minutes or hours to  load for 'B' in production server sometime,it was loading properly in production server  with the same data till last two days(within 7 seconds) whereas it is always loading faster in test server.If we ran a query against a table in sql query browser with 'begin tran' and if it is not committed  ,then our application features related to this  table will not work until we are committing it. I am getting the same experience while i am trying to search the records of 'B' some time even none of our developers have logged into production database server in that moments.I am not sure why it is happening.The maximum number of users will work on this feature concurrently may be 10.It is occurring in some day and  the issue may persist for few days and it may work properly in some day.

Comment: when that happens, have a look at the "Blocking transactions"-report in SQL Server. Maybe one transaction blocks the table B and everything else has to wait for the transaction to either commit or rollback. You have to make sure to always either commit or rollback your transactions.

Comment: I checking using activity monitor for blocked transaction,but i could not find any blocked transactions.